# Better way to listen to specific port with some custom protocol on JBoss AS 7.1

Tags: java, jboss7.x

There is some integration which comes with existed protocols and ports. No HTTP no JSON just plain HEX. I need to listen on this port and accept connection.

I see one solution - servlet. This way I can also manage count of thread which will handle connections but may be JBoss 7.1 provide something to do this better.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a servlet and get it to manage threads for you unless it speaks HTTP.

The solution to your problem consists of a standard ServerSocket, accept loop, thread per connection scenario,or else an NIO implementation if you are brave.

Comment: I feeling bad about using such low-level technology on JBoss but it seems I must in the end. Thank You.

Comment: If it's your custom protocol, you have to implement it, don't you?

Comment: Yes but I prefer if JBoss manage connection, create thread for each but I handle data flow. Of course I dont think what JBoss can handle data flow of custom protocol. I think question closed. I get answer. Thank You.